# Difference between composition and function application

Tags: haskell

The first problem in [99 Haskell Problems](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10) is to "find the last element of a list". I came up with two solutions:

**Solution 1 (This works)**

```
myLast :: [a] -> a
myLast = head . reverse
```

**Solution 2 (This doesn't work)**

```
myLast :: [a] -> a
myLast = head $ reverse
```

**Question**

- Why does solution 1 work but not solution 2? What I'm most confused by is how neither implementations supply pattern matching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`head` is a function of one argument<sup>1</sup>. If you use `f $ x` to apply a function to something, it's the same as simply writing `f x` (or if you like `f(x)`, or `(f)x`, all the same thing... just uglier): the argument is "filled in" by the specified variable. So the result of `head $ reverse` will simply be whatever result `head` gives you when fed with an argument of `reverse`'s type... ...which however doesn't work, because `head` needs a list but `reverse` is a function. `$` itself doesn't care about this but just hands on the parameter, for instance you could write

> Prelude> :t map $ reverse
>   map $ reverse :: [[a]] -> [[a]]

because the first argument of `map` is in fact a function.

With `(.)` it's different. That cares about what type the argument to its right has (must also be a function), and it doesn't simply feed it to the left function right away. Rather, `f . g` yields *another* function, which does the following: it waits for some argument `x`, which it feeds to `g`, and then feeds *the result of that* to `f`.

Now, if you write

```
myLast' = head . reverse
```

it means just, you define `myLast` as this function that `(.)` gives you as the composition of `head` and `reverse`. That there are no arguments mentioned for `myLast` here doesn't matter: `[a] -> a` is just some type so you can define variables with this type (like myLast), by assigning them to values that happen to have such a function type (like `head . reverse`). You *could*, if you wanted, make the parameter explicit:

```
myLast'' x = (head . reverse) x
```

Note that the parens are needed because otherwise it's parsed as `head . (reverse x)` – which wouldn't work, because `reverse x` is not a function anymore, just a result list. And therefore you couldn't *compose* it with `head`; what you could however do is *apply* `head` to it:

```
myLast''' x = head $ reverse x
```

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, *every* function in Haskell has just one argument... but we say "two-argument function" for things like `(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int`, though really this is a one-argument function returning a one-argument function returning an `Int`: `(+) :: Int -> (Int -> Int)`.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly, application (`$`) is used between a function and its argument (a list in this case), while composition (`.`) is used between two functions.

About pattern matching: in the first solution, the function `reverse` will perform the needed pattern match for you, so `myLast` does not have to.